# Java Tomcat web form submission tries to download foo.do entry text/x-server-parsed-html

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, struts

Web form submssion tries to download `foo.do` (for example). This downloaded form is the "thanks for submitting" the user normally sees after submission. The email that this page sends comes through OK.

Both the `shtml` from which the form is submitted and the response that tries to download have a meta content tag of `text/html`.

I havent got access to the classfile yet to see what my dev is doing and the Apache httpd directive that send stuff to Tomcat AJP13 haven't changed.

I've got a feeling that it's either in the class file that processes the request or in the web.xml file. Either a missing filter or an improper/dodgy process by the class handling `foo.do`.

Is this likely to be a server misconfiguration or a error in Java code?

Comment: Please post the entire set of response headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

et voila!

```
<mime-mapping>
        <extension>shtml</extension>
        <mime-type>text/x-server-parsed-html</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
```

was defined in  the C_B/conf/web.xml
changed that to 
text/html in my application web.xml

:)

Answer (score 0):

It's the *browser* that is trying to "download" the response, not the server.

With that said, the browser acts this way based on the response headers sent by the server - if the response is truly `text/html` make sure that the server is sending `Content-Type: text/html` in the response headers (values of the `<meta>` html tag won't matter here, because the browser isn't even considering the response as html).

Comment: I looked in the http conversation prior to aksing this and yes thanks for the above it restated something I hadnt said,perhaps I should have been more explicit.. after much digging I've found CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml might have defined shtml as mime text/x-server-parsed-html weiltry out a few things.. though I'd like to redefine this on a webapp basis not server wide..